# how to calculate expiry date using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: SQL Query in image]
Calculate expiry date using mysql query.
calculate make_date and expiry_date difference against tblt_name in mysql query.

Comment: It would appear you already have the expiry date available.  Then are you trying to compute the shelf life for each tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below query..

```
select tblt_name,
(CASE
WHEN datediff(expiry_date,CURDATE()) > 0 then datediff(expiry_date,CURDATE())
ELSE 'Expired'
END) as Remaining_days_expired from tablets;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21d6a/3)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT tblt_id, tblt_name, make_date, expiry_date, expiry_date - make_date AS shelf_life
FROM medicine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `DATEDIFF()` function to do so

```
SELECT tblt_id , tblt_name , DATEDIFF(s,expiry_date,make_date) FROM TABLE.
```

First para just put the different date type you wan to compare

`s` is just display the different in `Seconds` format.